# Properly reference figure?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Figure numbers using the section number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19651/figure-numbers-using-the-section-number)

I have a figure inside a section, like:

```
\subsection{Something}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[height=2in]{pictures/mathematic/vn_vicinity.pdf}
    \hspace{1.5in}\parbox{5in}{\caption{Representación gráfica Vecindad de Von Neumann}}
    \label{fig:VecindadVonNeumann}
\end{figure}
```

When I want to reference the figure:

```
This is my all awesome figure \ref{fig:VecindadVonNeumann}
```

I get the reference number from the section, not from the figure itself.

This is my section number

[image: Section Number]

This is my Figure, shows 2.1 as number
[image: Figure Number]

This is the number that I'm getting in my `\ref`

[image: 2.1.4]

Is this normal ? Shouldn't I get `2.1` in my reference ?

Comment: You should put the `\label` command inside the `\parbox`; however, customizing the appearance of the caption is best done with the `caption` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you you put the `\label` inside the `\parbox` argument, it works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
dummy graphics
\hspace{1.5in}\parbox{5in}{\caption{Representación gráfica Vecindad de Von Neumann}\label{fig:VecindadVonNeumann}}
\end{figure}
This is my all awesome figure \ref{fig:VecindadVonNeumann}
\end{document}
```

It looks like the `\parbox` separates the `\label` from the counter. As @egreg alread pointed out in his comment above, shaping the caption with such `\hspace` and `\parbox` things isn't quite good style. Better take the `caption` package or -- if you use one of them -- the built-in means of the KOMAscript classes.