# Mistakes in the figure numeration

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Figure numbers using the section number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19651/figure-numbers-using-the-section-number)
>   [Why does an environment’s label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

I have two figures in my document. Figure 1 is correctly entitled and referred, but figure 2 is entitled Fig 2, but referred as Fig 6.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \label{ExperimantalSetup}
  \caption{Block-scheme of the experimental setup}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{setup}
\end{figure}
```

I checked:

- no duplicate labels,
- no errors or warnings(excepting the image size) in compilation
- the only list which has #6 at that point of the document is the Todo list. (But I used the same Todo package before, and had no problems with it).
- references are not hyperlinked (not clickable).

Perhaps, there is a settings error, could you advice what to change? Any ideas why this problem can be?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Always place the label after or within the caption. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here StackOverflow. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.