# Wrong table numbers used in references

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, numbering

I am writing a thesis in `LaTeX`, using a class file provided by my institution. This class file uses the `hyperref` package.

My thesis contains figures, listings (using the package `listings`) and algorithms (using `algorithm2e`). All of these are typeset as floats.

The numbering in the captions of tables is in accordance with the other two kinds of floats, and how I wish it to be: `<chapter>.<counter>`. The counter seems to be reset at the beginning of every chapter. (for example, the first table in chapter 3 says "Table 3.1" in its caption, the second table in chapter 4 is captioned as "Table 4.2", etc)

However when using the `\ref{<label-inside-table-env>}` to refer to the tables anywhere, a wrong(ly formatted) number is used with seems to include the number of the `\section` as well (`<chapter>.<section>.<counter>`). This of course is not presentable. This doesn't happen for figures or other floats, only for tables.

First of all, I inspected the class file to make sure it isn't the culprit of this inconsistency. As far as my (very novice to LaTeX) eyes can tell, nothing in there seems relevant to my problem.

I compiled the document without the global `draft` option to make sure this wasn't the cause.

Next, I read many seemingly related answers about wrong reference numbers here on tex.sx and while I learned interesting stuff I found no solution to my specific problem.

Lastly, I checked the documentation of package `hyperref` in hopes of finding something there. I was unsuccesful.

It confuses me that I can find no hint of a command which configures numbering for tables differently than for other floats, and yet I see this inconsitent result.

My question thus is:

> *Where can I learn how to control the numbering of referenced figures/tables in LaTeX (when using the `hyperref` package, if that changes anything)?*

Just in case it is of interest/relevance, I provide both my main document and the class file below. My included chapters have nothing but content, no macro definitions at all, so I can pretty safely assume that if some inconsistent code is causing this problem, it is in one of the two files below.

## My main document (which doesn't change how things are numbered)

```
\documentclass[draft]{wissdoc}
%\documentclass[]{wissdoc}
% Autor: Roland Bless 1996-2009, bless <at> kit.edu
% Anpassungen von: Matthias Huber, Dirk Achenbach, Matthias Gabel
%                  (vorname.nachname@kit.edu)
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Studentische Ausarbeitung - Hauptdokument
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% wissdoc-Optionen: draft, relaxed, pdf --> siehe wissdoc.cls
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Weitere packages: (Dokumentation dazu durch "latex <package>.dtx")
%\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion,babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools} % This includes "amsmath" and the dcases environment among other things
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
% For tables:
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} %includes colortbl
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% For listings and source code
\usepackage[algo2e, %% To avoid environment name conflicts
            vlined,  %% Makes the scope of conditionals be a simple horizontal line with a knick
            ruled,  %% Prints top and bottom rules surrounding the algorith box, and the caption on top
            ]  
{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\mycmtsty}[1]{\small\texttt{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycmtsty}

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    stepnumber=1,
    captionpos=b,
    language=Java,
    frame=lines
}
% Other packages
\usepackage{tikz}
%% ---------------- end of usepackages -------------

% Index-Datei öffnen
\ifnotdraft{\makeindex}
%\ifnotdraft{\makeglossaries}

\begin{document}
% \newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=23mm,bottom=25mm,head=14.5pt}

%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Präambel
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\ifnotdraft{
 \include{titelseite}
 \blankpage % Leerseite auf Titelrückseite
 \include{erklaerung}  % Die folgende Erklärung ist (außer für Studienarbeiten) Pflicht (siehe Prüfungsordnung)
 \blankpage % Leerseite auf Erklärungsrückseite
}
\restoregeometry
\includechapter{abstract}

%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Inhaltsangaben
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\ifnotdraft{
    {\parskip 0pt\tableofcontents} % toc bitte einzeilig
    \blankpage
    \listoffigures
    \blankpage
    \listoftables
    \blankpage
}

%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Hauptteil
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{introduction}       % Einleitung
\include{implementation}     % Implementierung
\include{cryptanalysis}            % Das Zentralmotiv der Arbeit
\include{results}          % Irgendwas muss ja rausgekommen sein
\include{summary}           % Zusammenfassung und Ausblick

\appendix
\includechapter{appendix_kappa01}
\includechapter{appendix_2cyclical}
%\include{anhang_b}

%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Referenzen
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
% \bibliographystyle{geralpha} % abbrvnat unsrtnat
% Benutze Standard LaTeX-Support statt BibTeX
\includechapter{bibliography}
%\bibliography{ausarbeitung}

%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Index
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\ifnotdraft{
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \printindex            % Index, Stichwortverzeichnis
}

\end{document}
```

## The class file (nothing of relevance as far as my untrained eye could see)

```
%% Encoding: ISO8859-1 %%

%% LaTeX2e Formatklasse f�r Diplom-, Studien- oder Doktorarbeit    -*-Mode: LaTeX;-*-
%% Autor: Roland Bless 1996-2006 bless <at> tm.uka.de
%% --
%% (falls die Umlaute nicht richtig dargestellt werden: 
%%  der benutzte Zeichensatz ist UTF-8!)
%% Hinweis f�r Literatur zu LaTeX 2e:
%% 1. Leslie Lamport: "Das LaTeX-Handbuch", Addison-Wesley
%% 2. Goosens, Mittelbach, Samarin: "Der LaTeX-Begleiter"
%% Referenz und Grundbefehle sind in 1. zu finden, 2. erkl�rt
%% Zusatz-Pakete, die einem Dokument ein individuelleres Aussehen verleihen
%% k�nnen.
%%
%% Zusatzpakete und LaTeX k�nnen von ftp://ftp.dante.de bezogen werden
%% Fragen zu LaTeX: siehe FAQ auf http://www.dante.de
%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01] % Sorry, wir brauchen LaTeX2e!
\ProvidesClass{wissdoc}[2007/01/18 Roland Bless - Wissenschaftliches Dokument]
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{book} % diese Klasse basiert auf ``book''
\RequirePackage{ngerman}[1998/07/08] % (V2.5e) Neue Rechtschreibung!
%\RequirePackage{german}[1998/07/08] % alte Rechtschreibung (>=V2.5e von german.sty)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % T1-encoded fonts: auch W�rter mit Umlauten trennen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Eingabe nach UTF-8
\usepackage{ae}               % almost european, virtueller T1-Font
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}  % um Graphiken einzubinden
\usepackage{makeidx}          % wir wollen auch einen Index
\usepackage[a4paper,includehead,includefoot]{geometry} % Seitenr�nder einstellen leichtgemacht
\usepackage{fancyhdr}         % definiere einfache Headings (mindestens V 1.99c
                            % notwendig)
\usepackage{array}          % fuer aufw�ndigere Tabellen
\usepackage{xcolor}             % Farbunterst�tzung
\usepackage{colortbl}       % farbige Tabellen (v. D. Carlisle)
\usepackage{longtable}      % seiten�bergreifende Tabellen

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[T1]{url} % much like \verb allow line breaks for paths and URLs

% Postscript Fonts
% times, palatino, newcent, bookman, garamond, basker, 
% lucid, lucidbrb, lucidbry (Kommerzielle Fonts von Y&Y)
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{palatino}
% \usepackage{newcent}      %for sophisticated font style

% other interesting packages:
% \usepackage{varioref}
% \usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{subfigure}
% \usepackage{shadow} % f�r schattierte Boxen etc.
% \usepackage{tabularx} % automatische Spaltenbreite
% \usepackage{supertab} % mehrseitige Tabellen
%% ---------------- end of usepackages -------------

%% Options
% Optionen:
% draft - L��t Titelseite, Inhaltsverzeichnis, Index, etc. weg.
%         Daf�r mu� allerdings die Unterst�tzung in der LaTeX Hauptdatei
%         vorhanden sein (\ifnotdraft{\include{bla...}}).
% relaxed - erlaubt etwas unsch�nere Abst�nde f�r automatische Zeilenumbr�che
% pdf     - setzt Optionen f�r pdf (wird aber automatisch bei pdflatex aktiviert)
\DeclareOption{draft}{\let\@draft\@empty}
\DeclareOption{relaxed}{\tolerance=1500 \emergencystretch=12pt}
\DeclareOption{pdf}{\@usepdfttrue}
%% Modifications
\let\@draft\@undefined %no draft
\newif\if@usepdf \@usepdffalse % not pdf ready
\ProcessOptions

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % Numerierung auch f�r \subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    % nimm auch \subsubsections ins Inhaltsverz. auf

%% Schusterjungen und Hurenkinder verhindern.
%% Siehe deutsches TeX-FAQ (6.1.3)
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

%% New Commands
\newcommand{\ifnotdraft}[1]{\ifx\@draft\@undefined #1 \fi}
\newcommand{\ifnotdraftelse}[2]{\ifx\@draft\@undefined #1 \else #2 \fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PDF dependent stuff (inspired by Frank P�hlke)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifx\pdftexversion\@undefined % kein PDFTeX aktiv
\else
\@usepdftrue % switch automatically to PDF mode
\fi

\if@usepdf
\usepackage{ae}      % erzeuge lesbare Schriften (mit cmps-Fonts)
\usepackage{color}   % f�r farbige Hyperlinks ben�tigt
\usepackage[raiselinks=true,%
           bookmarks=true,%
           bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
           bookmarksopen=true,%
           bookmarksnumbered=true,%
           hyperindex=true,% 
           plainpages=false,% correct hyperlinks
           pdfpagelabels=true,% view TeX pagenumber in PDF reader
           pdfborder={0 0 0.5}]{hyperref} % erzeuge Hyperlinks z.B. f�r pdflatex
%\usepackage[CJKbookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{thumbpdf}
\pdfcompresslevel=9   % scheint zwar nichts zu bringen, aber was soll's
\else
\usepackage{nohyperref}
\fi

\newif\if@usehyperref
\ifx\href\@undefined % Wenn kein hyperref Paket geladen
    \@usehyperreffalse % hyperref used
\else
    \@usehyperreftrue % hyperref used
\fi


% Das float-Paket muss NACH hyperref eingebunden werden,
% sonst klappt die PDF-Ausgabe nicht:
%\usepackage{float} %z.B. \floatstyle{ruled}

%% Seitengr��e mit geometry-Paket einstellen
\geometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=23mm,bottom=25mm,head=14.5pt}
%\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=23mm,bottom=25mm,head=14.5pt}

% Achtteilung in Rasterma�, Bindekorrektur 12mm:
%\geometry{left=38mm, right=52mm, top=37mm, bottom=74mm, head=14.5pt}

% Neunteilung in Rasterma�, Bindekorrektur 12mm:
% BEI BINDEKORREKTUR MUSS NEU GEMESSeN WERDEN!
%\geometry{left=35mm, right=46mm, top=33mm, bottom=66mm, head=14.5pt}

% (Das wollen wir eigentlich sp�ter)
%% Neunteilung in Rasterma�, Bindekorrektur 0mm:
%%\geometry{left=23mm, right=46mm, top=33mm, bottom=66mm, head=14.5pt}

% Elfteilung im Rasterma�, Bindekorrektur 0mm:
%\geometry{left=19.1mm, right=28.2mm, top=27mm, bottom=54mm, head=14.5pt}

% Elfteilung im Rasterma�, Bindekorrektur 10mm:
%\geometry{left=28.18mm, right=36.36mm, top=27mm, bottom=54mm, head=14.5pt}

% Zehnteilung im Rasterma�, Bindekorrektur 0mm:
%\geometry{left=21mm, right=42mm, top=29.7mm, bottom=59.4mm, head=14.5pt}



%% Stil
\parindent 0cm                     % Absatzanfang wird nicht einger�ckt
\parskip1.5ex plus0.5ex minus0.5ex % Abstand zwischen zwei Abs�tzen

%\newcommand{\headfont}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
%\newcommand{\headfont}{\sffamily}
\newcommand{\headfont}{\slshape}
\newcommand{\captionfont}{}
\newcommand{\chapterheadfont}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Headings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Geaenderte Headings:
%% Seitenzahl normal, Text in slanted und nicht in Grossbuchstaben
%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\headfont\thepage}} % left/right header for even/odd pages
\fancyhead[LO]{\headfont\nouppercase{\rightmark}} % header for left side (odd)
\fancyhead[RE]{\headfont\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % right header for even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % head rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % no rule
% plainstyle
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%\cfoot{\headfont\thepage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Linien f�r Bilder (ben�tigt float.sty)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Achtung! Folgende Änderungen sind evtl. vom benutzten float.sty abh�ngig,
% d.h. bei Änderungen des float.sty sind folgende Makros nicht mehr definiert
% oder unwirksam. In diesem Fall mu� erneut angepa�t werden.
\newlength{\float@capnamewd}   % neu
\newlength{\float@cparwidth}   % neu
\newsavebox{\float@capnamebox} % neu
\renewcommand\floatc@ruled[2]{%
\savebox{\float@capnamebox}{\@fs@cfont #1\hspace*{1.5ex}}
\settowidth{\float@capnamewd}{\usebox{\float@capnamebox}}%
\setlength{\float@cparwidth}{\hsize}%
\addtolength{\float@cparwidth}{-1.0\float@capnamewd}%
\usebox{\float@capnamebox}\parbox[t]{\float@cparwidth}{#2\par}}
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
\def\@fs@pre{}%
\def\@fs@post{\kern2.5pt\hrule height.1pt depth0pt\relax}%
\def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule height.1pt depth0pt \kern2.5pt}%
\def\@fs@cfont{\captionfont\bfseries}
\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Stil der Ueberschriften
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@startsection{section}%
{1}% Gliederungsebene
{0mm}% Einzug
{1.5ex plus 1ex minus 1.2ex}% Vorabstand
{0.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}% Nachabstand
{\chapterheadfont\Large\bfseries}% Stil
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
\@startsection{subsection}%
{2}%
{0mm}%
{1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}%
{0.3ex plus 0.3ex minus 0.3ex}%
{\chapterheadfont\large\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
\@startsection{subsubsection}%
{3}%
{0mm}%
{1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}%
{0.2ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.2ex}%
{\chapterheadfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
\@startsection{paragraph}%
{4}%
{0mm}%
{2ex plus 1ex minus 2ex}%
{0.2ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.2ex}%
{\chapterheadfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Stil der Kapitelueberschrift 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\chapnolen}
\newlength{\chapparlen}
\newsavebox{\chapno}
%% Kein ``Kapitel'' bei Kapitel�berschrift
% \renewcommand{\@chapapp}{} allein reicht nicht!
%% \chapter{...}
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{0.2\textheight}%
%\hrule
\vskip 15\p@
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
      \savebox{\chapno}{\chapterheadfont\huge\bfseries \thechapter.}
      \settowidth{\chapnolen}{\usebox{\chapno}}
      \parbox[t]{\chapnolen}{\usebox{\chapno}}\nobreak\leavevmode
%        \par\nobreak
%        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
  \fi
  \interlinepenalty\@MM
  \setlength{\chapparlen}{\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\chapparlen}{-1.0\chapnolen}
  \addtolength{\chapparlen}{-2ex}
  \leavevmode\nobreak
  \parbox[t]{\chapparlen}{\raggedright\chapterheadfont\huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
  %\the\textwidth
  %\the\chapparlen
  %\the\chapnolen
  %\vskip 20\p@
  %\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \vskip 40\p@
}}

%% \chapter*{...}
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
  \normalfont
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \chapterheadfont \huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
  \vskip 40\p@
}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Inhaltsverzeichnis (auch andere Fontfamilie)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{\contentsname}\chapterheadfont\oldtableofcontents}}
\let\@olddottedtocline\@dottedtocline
\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{\@olddottedtocline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\chapterheadfont #5}}

%% pagestyle fuer Titelseite:
\def\titlehead#1{\def\@titlehead{#1}}
\def\titlefoot#1{\def\@titlefoot{#1}}
\def\@titlehead{}
\def\@titlefoot{}

\def\ps@title{%
\headheight 15mm
\footskip   0cm
\addtolength{\textheight}{-15mm}
\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo%
\def\@oddhead{\vbox{\hbox to\textwidth{\@titlehead}
              \vskip 1.5mm
              \hbox to\textwidth{\hrulefill}}}
\def\@oddfoot{\vbox{\vskip -1mm\hbox to\textwidth{\hrulefill}\vskip 1mm
              \hbox to\textwidth{\@titlefoot}}}
\let\@evenhead\@oddhead
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
{%
\let\oldheadheight\headheight
\let\oldfootskip\footskip
\let\oldtextheight\textheight

 \cleardoublepage
 \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \else
    \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{title}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
}%
{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
\if@twoside\else
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
\fi
\let\headheight\oldheadheight
\let\textheight\oldtextheight
\let\footskip\oldfootskip
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Bibliography 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Stil Index-Seite
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewenvironment{theindex}
{\if@twocolumn
 \@restonecolfalse
\else
 \@restonecoltrue
\fi
\columnseprule \z@
\columnsep 35\p@
\twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}]%
\@mkboth{\indexname}%
       {\indexname}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\flushbottom
\parindent\z@
\parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
\let\item\@idxitem
\def\,{\relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip
            \else\hskip0.2em\ignorespaces\fi}%
\raggedright}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
```

Comment: I cannot see where you create, label and refer to figures, but you are most likely placing your label in the wrong place., This should come after or within the caption.

Comment: Yep, you are completely right. Just after I posted, I saw [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19651/reference-to-a-figure-uses-the-sections-number?rq=1) in the list of related questions. It seems the system is already better at searching for related questions than me, cause I didn't find that one when searching for help before asking. I checked, and found precisely that mistake. Now, if you'll indulge me... what is happening (internally) that causes a wrong number instead of an error if the `label` command *has* to follow `section`?

Comment: I don't know if it's proper etiquette to delete my question, but since my problem was kindly solved by the remark @AubreyBlumsohn made, I would like to - just don't wanna ruffle any feathers. Any mods reading who know if I should go ahead?

Comment: Put simply, the label has to know what its labeling. If the last label-able thing it saw was a section break then that is what it will label.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Yes, that makes sense. Thank you ;)