# Reference to a figure uses the section's number in ccaption package

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I have the similar issue with [Reference to a figure uses the section's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19651/reference-to-a-figure-uses-the-sections-number), but with the `ccaption` package to use the bilingual caption, I put the label after `bicaption`, but I can not handle the problem? It should be Figure 1 
or 图1 instead of section 2.1.Does anyone have suggestion, thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\begin{document}
  \section{sssection}
  \section{oneone   }
    \subsection{kkkkk}
     \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{pic/PEF_prin} 
          % a local figure should be replaced
        \bicaption{图}{中文}{Fig}{English title}
        \label{fig:key11}
    \end{figure}
    see Figure\ref{fig:key11}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label should be passed as an optional argument to `\bicaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\begin{document}
    \section{sssection}
    \section{oneone   }
    \subsection{kkkkk}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image} 
        \bicaption[fig:key11]{图}{中文}{Fig}{English title}
    \end{figure}
    see Figure~\ref{fig:key11}
\end{document}
```

[image: fig]